# Rounding decimal value

Tags: c#, floating-point

I am facing problem while rounding the decimal value in C# using `Math.Round(a, 2);`

When I'm rounding 1.275 by 2 decimal points, the result is 1.27.
When I'm doing the same for 1.375, the result is 1.38.

Why is it not rounding 1.275 to 1.28?

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, haven't found the screenshot ;-) but I have found this blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/sfurman/archive/2003/03/07/3537.aspx

Comment: Are you actually using a `decimal` value, or are you using `double`?

Comment: It is a little confusing when you say that you round the `decimal` value; `Math.Round(1.275m, 2) = 1.28`, whereas if you use the `double` overload you get, as you write, `Math.Round(1.275, 2) = 1.27`. Problem is most likely due to inaccuracy in the floating point representation.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
Math.Round(1.275m, 2) => 1.28m
Math.Round(1.375m, 2) => 1.38m
```

I suspect that your claim that you use a `decimal` value is false, and that you use `double` value instead. `double` can't represent many decimal values exactly, so when you write `1.275`, it's actually 1.27499... `1.375`  is one of the few representable onces, so it's actually `1.375`.

If your code cares about exact decimal representation, for example when you work on money, you *must* use `decimal` and not binary floating point such as `double` or `float`.

---

But even if you use decimal representation, rounding behaves unexpectedly for many users:

```
Math.Round(1.265m, 2) => 1.26m
Math.Round(1.275m, 2) => 1.28m
```

By default `Math.Round` uses [`MidpointRounding.ToEven`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx), also known as [Banker's rounding](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/). This avoids accumulating a bias from always rounding up at `.5`.

You can use an overload of `Round` that takes a rounding mode, and set it to `AwayFromZero` to get the behaviour you expect.

```
Math.Round(1.275m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) => 1.28m
```

Comment: That would be the explanation if 1.275 rounded to 1.28, but it doesn't.

Comment: `1.275m` is not the same as `1.275`. The OP asked for `1.275`.

Comment: The "problem" is reproducible, just don't cast it to decimal

Comment: the OP talked about decimal values. `1.275` as double is no decimal value (at least not equal to the decimal value 1.275).

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think he meant "decimal" values in the "lay" sense of the word, not the computer science sense...

Comment: Try This --  double a =1.275;
            double b = 1.375;
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(a, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(b, 2));

Comment: @user1565811 `double` is not `decimal`. I read your original post as you using `decimal`. Using `Math.Round(double, int)` is almost always wrong, because double cannot meaningfully represent decimal values.

Comment: `1.375` is represented exactly as both a decimal and as a double.

Answer (score 7):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) has this to say regarding this behavior:

> **Notes to Callers**
>
> Because of the loss of precision that can result from
> representing decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing
> arithmetic operations on floating-point values, in some cases the
> Round(Double, Int32) method may not appear to round midpoint values to
> the nearest even value in the digits decimal position. This is
> illustrated in the following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13
> instead of 2.14. This occurs because internally the method multiplies
> value by 10<sup>digits</sup>, and the multiplication operation in this case
> suffers from a loss of precision.

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      double[] values = { 2.125, 2.135, 2.145, 3.125, 3.135, 3.145 };
      foreach (double value in values)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value, Math.Round(value, 2));

   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       2.125 --> 2.12
//       2.135 --> 2.13
//       2.145 --> 2.14
//       3.125 --> 3.12
//       3.135 --> 3.14
//       3.145 --> 3.14
```

Comment: If the method returns an incorrect result because internally it does something that is inaccurate, then the implementation is incorrect. More likely, the MSDN documentation is wrong, and Math.Round returns an unexpected result because the caller did not realize the value they were passing was not what they thought. E.g., in the question asked here, the caller was not passing 1.275 but was passing a value slightly less than 1.275. The error occurred **before** calling Math.Round, not **in** it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `Decimal` value, it will correctly round `1.275` to `1.28`.

If you have a `Double` value, it will not behave the same, because the value `1.275` can not be represented exactly. If you use the `double` value `1.275`, it will actually be slightly smaller than the exact value `1.275`, something like `1.2749999999999999`.

When rounding that value, it will not be exacly between `1.27` and `1.28` but slightly closer to `1.27`, so it will be rounded down instead of up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible hack, but try using Format. It inexplicably uses the rounding we're all used to.

```
Val(Format(2.25, "0.0")) returns 2.3
```

(OR)

Just for information: From .Net version 2.0 its possible to define the way the "0.5 cases" are rounded with a parameter MidpointRounding. It can be either ToEven or AwayFromZero. So "standard" rounding would be like this:

```
Math.Round(2.25, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

This would return value "2.3".

Answer (score 1):

```
Format(1.275, "0.00"))
```

as suggested in this blog's comments: http://weblogs.asp.net/sfurman/archive/2003/03/07/3537.aspx

Which version of the .Net framework do you use? If it is above 1.1, you can use the [midpointrounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set it to `AwayFromZero`

```
Math.Round(1.275, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's because your rounding a double, and not a decimal:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.275M, 2)); // outputs 1.28
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.375M, 2)); // outputs 1.38
```

Decimal and doubles are very different

Answer (score 0):

Expected behaviour as per the documentation.

> For example, if decimals is equal to 1, 2.15 and 2.15000 are both
>   rounded to 2.2 because .05 and .05000 are both halfway between .1 and
>   .2, and .1 is odd. Similarly, if decimals is equal to 1, 2.05 and
>   2.05000 are both rounded to 2.0 because .05 and .05000 are both halfway between .0 and .1, and .0 is even.   The behavior of this
>   method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This kind of rounding is
>   sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's rounding. It
>   minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently rounding a
>   midpoint value in a single direction.   To control the type of
>   rounding used by the Round(Decimal, Int32) method, call the
>   Decimal.Round(Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding) overload.

From [Math.Round(decimal, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx).  Try

```
Decimal.Round(a, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```